# Authentication and Authorize with Jwt Bearer Claims/Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt

I'm trying to create an authorize with jwt bearer, but I cant do it on my application, when I do with postman it happening what I want, but on my app don't...

Service.ts (Angular 8)

```
getAll(): Observable<...[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<...[]>(environment.url + "api",
    { headers: {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token });
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    var symetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"]));
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = symetricSecurityKey
            };
        });
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

AuthController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public async Task<AccountModel> Login([FromBody] AccountModel model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        var signInResultado = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        }).Wait();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password);
        }).Wait();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            signInResultado = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
            user.UserName,
            model.Password,
            isPersistent: false,
            lockoutOnFailure: false);
        }).Wait();

        if (signInResultado.Succeeded)
        {
            var appUser = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id);
            var claims = await GetValidClaims(appUser);
            var accountModel = new AccountModel(user, _roleManager);

            accountModel.Token = GenerateJwtToken(appUser, claims);
            return accountModel;
        }

    }
    return model;
}
private string GenerateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user, List<Claim> claims)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtKey"]);


    var tokens = new JwtSecurityToken(
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokens);

}
private async Task<List<Claim>> GetValidClaims(ApplicationUser user)
{
    IdentityOptions _options = new IdentityOptions();
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType, user.UserName)
    };
    var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    claims.AddRange(userClaims);
    foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
        var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(userRole);
        if (role != null)
        {
            var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            foreach (Claim roleClaim in roleClaims)
            {
                claims.Add(roleClaim);
            }
        }
    }
    return claims;
}
```

Any method with Role = Admin

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<RoleModel>> Get()
```

Postman - Login (Create Token)

[image]

Postman - Get any method with Role = Admin

[image]

When I did on my application, it redirected to Identity/Account/Login

[image]
[image]

Comment: As you censored all urls: are they correct? In your Service.ts there is something missing after the api part. What is written to the log?

Comment: it's all url correct, because if I remove the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` its work... where I can see the log? (console? if its, there is nothing written in the log)

Comment: Yeah when you are not running with IIS it's showing a console with logs. Authentication Middleware also writes its logs there

Comment: But where, at chrome console? there is nothing there

Comment: Not related but this monstrous `Task.Run( async () .... ).Wait()` looks horrible. Why would you wrap a typical async call with `Task.Run(...).Wait()`?

Comment: I work with a team @WiktorZychla and I can't change other people's code, told me to study and do JWT and that's what I'm doing... I didn't mean to be ignorant, sorry it seemed

Comment: Whoever wrote this code, ask them to double check that, refer to this discussion here. As for your problem, are you sure your header is here when called from the browser?

Comment: @LeoHenrique I don't find `signInResultado` variable is assigned any value after it is initialized. So may be `signInResultado.Succeeded` is false. Also, go to https://jwt.io/ and decode your token to ensure that claims are added to JWT token

Comment: @MohsinMehmood, I updated the post with the entire login method... I already decode with jwt.io and I have the claims that I need...

Comment: @WiktorZychla, I don't know if that anwsers you question, but when I create a policy (my first test), I can enter on method with Authorize(Policy = "Policy"), so if that information is sent with token too, so I think that I have the token on header

Comment: @LeoHenrique Have you confirmed that `Authorization` header is set when call is initiated from Angular app to `/api` end point? Verify in Request headers

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I updated the post with request header

Comment: I took the token by the request header and tested it on the postman and it worked, but coming from angular doesn't work

Comment: guys, I was able to do with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47025009/10647645 ... Thank you very much