# Azure AD v2.0-specific optional claims missing from ID Token

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-3.1, claims-authentication

I'm trying to add optional claims using Microsoft Identity Web - NuGet for user authentication in NET Core 3.1 WebApp. Reading the MS Docs, it seems that the only steps needed are to declare the optional claims within the App Registration Manifest file in Azure. But when testing the login process using two different apps (my own code and an MS project example) it looks like the optional claims are not being added to the ID Token when returned from Azure following a successful login i.e they're not present at all when viweing the token details in Debug.

I'm not sure how to diagnose this and where to trace the issue i.e am I missing any required steps in Azure setup?

Side Note: Just to confirm it is the jwt ID Token I want to receive the additional claims, NOT the jwt access token used for calling the graph or another Web API endpoint.

MS Docs reference: [v2.0-specific optional claims set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims)

Below is the extract from the Manifest file: (note I've even declared the "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2, given that optional claims I'm using are not available in ver.1, which if the above was left at default 'null' value then Azure will assume we're using legacy ver.1 - a possible gotcha)

```
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "given_name",
            "source": "user",
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": []
        },
        {
            "name": "family_name",
            "source": "user",
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": []
        }
    ],
    "accessToken": [],
    "saml2Token": []
},
```

Extract from startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Added to original .net core template.
        // ASP.NET Core apps access the HttpContext through the IHttpContextAccessor interface and 
        // its default implementation HttpContextAccessor. It's only necessary to use IHttpContextAccessor 
        // when you need access to the HttpContext inside a service.
        // Example usage - we're using this to retrieve the details of the currrently logged in user in page model actions.
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        // DO NOT DELETE (for now...)
        // This 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI' library was originally used for Azure Ad authentication 
        // before we implemented the newer Microsoft.Identity.Web and Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI NuGet packages. 
        // Note after implememting the newer library for authetication, we had to modify the _LoginPartial.cshtml file.
        //services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        //    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        ///////////////////////////////////

        // Add services required for using options.
        // e.g used for calling Graph Api from WebOptions class, from config file.
        services.AddOptions();

        // Add service for MS Graph API Service Client.
        services.AddTransient<OidcConnectEvents>();

        // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
        services.AddSignIn(Configuration);

        // Token acquisition service based on MSAL.NET
        // and chosen token cache implementation
        services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { Constants.ScopeUserRead })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        // Add the MS Graph SDK Client as a service for Dependancy Injection.
        services.AddGraphService(Configuration);

        ///////////////////////////////////

        // The following lines code instruct the asp.net core middleware to use the data in the "roles" claim in the Authorize attribute and User.IsInrole()
        // See https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2 for more info.
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            // The claim in the Jwt token where App roles are available.
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
        });

        // Adding authorization policies that enforce authorization using Azure AD roles. Polices defined in seperate classes.
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToViewLogsRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireRole(AppRole.ViewLogs));
        });

        ///////////////////////////////////

        services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        // Adds the service for creating the Jwt Token used for calling microservices.
        // Note we are using our independant bearer token issuer service here, NOT Azure AD
        services.AddScoped<JwtService>(); 
    }
```

Sample Razor PageModel method:

```
public void OnGet()
    {
        var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        var forename = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "given_name")?.Value;
        var surname = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "family_name")?.Value;

        _logger.LogInformation("" + username + " requested the Index page");
    }
```

*UPDATE*

Getting closer to a solution but not quite there yet. Couple of issues resolved:

1. I originally created the Tenant in Azure to use B2C AD, even though I was no longer using B2C and had switched to Azure AD. It wasn't until I deleted the tenant and created a new one before I started to see the optional claims come through to the webapp correctly. After creating the new tenant and assigning the tenant type to use Azure AD, I then found that the 'Token Configuration' menu was now available for configuring the optional claims through the UI, it seems that modifying the App manifest is still required as well, as shown above.

[image]

2. I had to add the 'profile' scope as type 'delegated' to the webapp API Permissions in Azure.

[image]

The final issue still unresolved is that although I can see the claims present during Debug, I cant figure out how to retrieve the claim values.

In the method below, I can see the required claims when using Debug, but can't figure out how to retrieve the values:

```
public void OnGet()
    {
        var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        var forename = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "given_name")?.Value;
        var surname = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "family_name")?.Value;

        _logger.LogInformation("" + username + " requested the Index page");
    }
```

Debug Screenshots shows the given_name & family_name are present:

[image]

[image]

I've tried different code examples using the claims principal to try and get the values out, but nothing is working for me. Hoping this final riddle is fairly simple to someone who knows the required syntax, as said we now have the required optional claims present, its just not knowing how to actually get the values out.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v20-specific-optional-claims-set) the optional claim `given_name` and `family_name` requires `profile` scope. In your token request have you specified the profile scope? You confirm that by looking at the HTTP traffic in browser devTools.

Comment: After adding profile scope to the app under API Permissions (Type = delegated) still not working for me though. Admin consent has been granted as well.

Comment: Extract from HTTP traffic request in devTools is 'id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20User.Read&response...'

Comment: Type name is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname` not just surname, you can use .NET framework ClaimTypes class. You could use `HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value`; For more information you can refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes?view=netframework-4.7).

Comment: Many thanks for your help, this is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big thanks to 'Dhivya G - MSFT Identity' for their assistance (see comments below my original question) method below now allows me to access the required claim values from the Token ID returned from Azure following successful login.

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        var forename = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;
        var surname = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value;

        _logger.LogInformation("" + username + " requested the Index page");
    }
```